# how to add new tr after add two td using smarty

Tags: php, html, smarty

my smarty code is like this i want to add new tr after adding two td **$k** is counter variable with this code i can not add new tr after every two td

```
    {section name="sec" loop=$dataArray}
      <tr>
        {if ($k%2) ==  0}  
        <td>{$dataArray[sec].itemNm}</td>
        <td>{$dataArray[sec].rate}</td>
        <td>{$dataArray[sec].unitId}</td>
        <td>{$dataArray[sec].packing}</td>
      </tr>
      {/if}
  {/section}
```

My Php Select Query is like

```
$selectdata = "SELECT *,itemNm FROM price
                      JOIN item ON item.itemId = price.itemId
                      WHERE price.companyId = ".$companyId;
      $selectdataRes = mysql_query($selectdata);
      while($dataRow = mysql_fetch_array($selectdataRes))
      {
        $dataArray[$k]['priceId']  = $dataRow['priceId'];
        $dataArray[$k]['itemNm']  = $dataRow['itemNm'];
        $dataArray[$k]['rate']    = $dataRow['rate'];
        $dataArray[$k]['unitId']  = $dataRow['unitId'];
        $dataArray[$k]['packing'] = $dataRow['packing'];
        $k++;
      }
```

Comment: I don't see any loop on anything looking like that...?

Comment: section is one kind of loop @Julqas

Comment: Then where is the incrementation of $k ? If you want to add a tr every two tds, you have to put that in a loop too ^^

Comment: @Julqas my code is updated with selected query...

Comment: I'm answering to make example for you

Answer (score 0):

You increment `$k` every loop of mysql_fetch_array, which means `$k` is the number of the row (aka TR in your HTML). If your SQL query returns 4 lines, each containing a `priceId`, `itemNm`, `rate`, `unitId` and `packing`.

Normally in your HTML, to represent it in a common table, you would have 4 lines TR (one TR for each row) with a column TD for each data you want to display (one TD for each data).

```
{section name="sec" loop=$dataArray}
    <tr>
        <td>{$dataArray[sec].itemNm}</td>
        <td>{$dataArray[sec].rate}</td>
        <td>{$dataArray[sec].unitId}</td>
        <td>{$dataArray[sec].packing}</td>
    </tr>
{/section}
```

If you perform a `$k%2 == 0`, you reach it every two rows (every two TR), not every two TD. If you want to close TR and open new TR every two TD and not every two TR, you have to handle your TDs in a loop and start another incrementing variable like this (example neither with smarty nor in any language in particular, just an idea of algorithm) :

```
for($k=0;$k<$numLines;$k++)
{
    <tr>
        for($l=0;$l<$numColumns;$l++)
        {
            if($l > 0 && $l%2 == 0)
            {
                </tr><tr>
            }

            <td>$myData[$l]</td>
        }
    </tr>
}
```

Hoping it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very hard to understand...
Do you want to split every data row in two table rows?
Since you have a static template, you can add table rows inside your loop, whereever you want. I see no need to use multiple loops.

```
{section name="sec" loop=$dataArray}
  <tr>
    <td>{$dataArray[sec].itemNm}</td>
    <td>{$dataArray[sec].rate}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{$dataArray[sec].unitId}</td>
    <td>{$dataArray[sec].packing}</td>
  </tr>
{/section}
```

if this does not fit your needs, maybe could you provide an example output as you need it?